# ClassCastException using converted List in Arrays.sort(...)

Tags: java

When I use Arrays.sort () with a comparator and a list as a collection, which is previously converted to an array, I get a class cast exception. This is my code:

```
List<SomeClazz> somes = new ArrayList<SomeClazz>();
Comparator<SomeClazz> attrComparator = new AttrComparator();

somes = createSomeObjectes(); // returnes a list of course

// this is line 25 where the exception occours
Arrays.sort((SomeClazz[])somes.toArray(), attrComparator);
```

The Exception-Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
    [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be 
    cast to [Lpack.SomeClazz; at pack.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:25)
```

What could be the reason for this? thx in advance!

Comment: `Comparator<SomeClass>` and `List<SomeClazz>`. Typo or a lurking `ClassCastException`?

Comment: typo, didn't see that, sry

Comment: Why are you not using `Collections.sort(somes, attrComparator);` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(SomeClazz[])somes.toArray()
```

should be

```
somes.toArray(new SomeClazz[somes.size()])
```

You can't cast an `Object[]` to a `SomeClazz[]`, but this is the "approved" way to dump a collection into an array type of your choice.

Comment: Or `somes.toArray(new SomeClazz[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

As per javadoc of `List.toArray`

> Object[] java.util.List.toArray()
>
> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper
>   sequence (from first to last element).
>
> The returned array will be "safe" in that no references to it are
>   maintained by this list. (In other words, this method must allocate a
>   new array even if this list is backed by an array). The caller is thus
>   free to modify the returned array.
>
> This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based
>   APIs.

Instead use `List.toArray(T[] arr)`

```
<T> T[] toArray(T[] a);
```

specifically:

```
Arrays.sort(somes.toArray(new SomeClazz[]{}), attrComparator);
```